# Order an array of words based on another array of words

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an array like this:

```
unorderedArr = ['pear', 'apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'pineapple'];
```

I would like to order this array based on a other given array like this:

```
order = ['peach', 'apple', 'pineapple']
```

The preferred result would be:

```
orderedArr = ['peach', 'apple', 'pineapple', 'banana', 'pear'];
```

It doesn't matter on what index the words that are not in the order array are placed. It's not guaranteed that the words in the order array will be in the unordered array

**Current Code Solution**

I tried using a switch statement like this:

```
const orderedArr = []
unorderedArr.forEach(word => {
  switch (word) {
    case 'peach':
      orderedArr.push(word);
      break;

    case 'apple':
      orderedArr.push(word);
      break;

    case 'pineapple':
      orderedArr.push(word);
      break;

    default:
      orderedArr.push(word);
      break;
    }
});
```

But I found out that a switch statement doesn't check on the first case first.

Comment: are all the words in order guaranteed to be in unordedArr?

Comment: No, that's not guaranteed.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried and what's not working for you?

Comment: Your sort comparator should use the index of the word in the ordering guide array, or just a big number (`Number.MAX_VALUE`) for words not listed. Then it'd be just a normal call to `.sort()` with that comparator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there's an easy non-programmatic way of doing this. What you need is an algorithm that yields the desired result, like this:

```js
function partialOrder(preferences, data)
{
  var result, reminder;

  result = [];

  // find preferences and put them into result
  preferences.forEach((name) => {
    result = result.concat(
      data.filter((d) => d.name === name)
    );
  });

  // find remaining data not in preferences
  reminder = data.filter((item) =>
    preferences.indexOf(item.name) === -1
  );

  return result.concat(reminder);
}

var preferences = [ "peach", "pear", "pineapple", "<alien-fruit>" ];
var data = [
  { "name": "apple", "image_url": "xApple" },
  { "name": "pineapple", "image_url": "xPineapple" },
  { "name": "peach", "image_url": "xPeach" },
  { "name": "pear", "image_url": "xPear" },
  { "name": "banana", "image_url": "xBanana" }
];

console.log(partialOrder(preferences, data));
```

Comment: Won't this end up with strings from the "ordered" list that don't appear in the array to be sorted?

Comment: Yes you are right! I've amended my answer with the "common" part which contains only the values in common. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of course I'm not actually working these strings, but with objects that I get from an api. I want to sort on a property called 'name'. So what I'm trying to do is: `(item) => unordered.indexOf(item.name) !== -1` but this don't seem to work for me.

Comment: I think this is better now. I've introduced the rather general method `existsByProperty()`, which can be used elsewhere if you need it.

Comment: Thanks! It is almost perfect, but it should return the given array with objects. Not the `{'name' : 'apple' }` object. It would be awesome if you could write some comments in the code, because I don't really understand what is exactly going on

Comment: You mean the array of strings (names)? Without the nested objects?

Comment: No the array that I get from the api call. Which looks a bit like this: `{name : 'example name', image_url : 'https://www.image.com/image', price : 12565}`. Right now it returns just this: `{name: "De Vakantiediscounter"}`, without all the other properties that should be on the object.

Comment: The method I've written should work with any objects that have a "name" property and leave all other properties untouched. Are you sure it's my methods that remove the other values?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185497/discussion-between-stijn-and-pid).

Comment: I've rewritten it all, hope this helps! I'm out now :)

Answer (score 4):

You could take an object for the sort order and a default value for items who have not an order.

```js
var array = ['pear', 'apple', 'banana', 'peach', 'pineapple'],
    wanted = ['peach', 'apple', 'pineapple'],
    order = Object.assign({ default: Infinity }, ...wanted.map((v, i) => ({ [v]: i + 1 })));
    
array.sort((a, b) => (order[a] || order.default) - (order[b] || order.default));

console.log(array);
```

Comment: to get 'banana' and 'pear' right you should alternatively sort alphabetically: `array.sort((a, b) => ((order[a] || order.default) - (order[b] || order.default) || a.localeCompare(b)));`

Comment: @HMR, op says: *"It doesn't matter on what index the words that are not in the order array are placed."*

Comment: ah, missed that. only looked at the sample output.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with simple logic;

```
var finalArray = [];

//loop over order array
for(var i=0; i<order.length; i++)   
{             
   //if order array element present into un-order array push in new array
   //this will ensure that in finalArray elements stays in order                  
   if(unordedArr.indexOf(order[i]) > -1)
       finalArray.push(order[i]);                                    
}

//loop over un-order array
for(var i=0; i<unordedArr.length; i++)    
{                    
   //if in final array the element is not present then enter it again  
   //which means the rest of the elements need to inserted
   if(finalArray.indexOf(unordedArr[i]) == -1)
   {
        finalArray.push(unordedArr[i]);  
   }
}                            

console.log(finalArray)
```